# Azure DevOps Can one turn off the YAML pipeline creation experience?

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, yaml, azure-pipelines, devops

I have projects in different AzureDevops instances created at different times.

In my current project the build pipeline has the New Yaml Pipeline Experience. My old projects have the old visual creation experience. Is it possible to toggle between the two views?

If so how do I go from the New YAML pipeline to the old view?

[This enable a preview link looks promising but the NEW YAML pipeline creation is no longer a toggle option for me](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/navigation/preview-features?view=azure-devops)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still create pipelines with the visual editor with the new YAML Pipeline features turned on.  Its easy to miss the option though.  Just create a new pipeline and then at the bottom of the page click the link for the classic editor.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to toggle between the two views?

If what you want is convert the current pipeline **which is using YAML** to view as Classic editor, sorry to say, no, we did not support this toggle between YAML and Classic Editor until now.

Now, we only support toggle the pipeline that code with Classic editor to YAML by using the "**View YAML**" button. But the reverse is not possible.

[image]

But I thinnk it would be a good feature that make configure in pipeline more convenient. Users can free to toggle between YAML and Classic Editor. You can raise this feature suggestion to our official [Suggestion Feature forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21), our Product Group and PMs will reviewing these ticket regularly, and consider to take it as our Roadmap.